# How are local variables referenced in closures?

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I am reading an article ([JavaScript Closures for Dummies](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies)) and one of the examples is as follows.

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

When testList is called, an alert box that says "item3 undefined".  The article has this explanation:

> When the anonymous functions are called on the line `fnlist[j]();` they all use the same single closure, and they use the current value for i and item within that one closure (where i has a value of 3 because the loop had completed, and item has a value of 'item3').

Why does item have a value of 'item3'?  Doesn't the for loop end when i becomes 3?  If it ends shouldn't item still be 'item2'?  Or is the variable item created again when testList calls the functions?

Comment: is it a bug that causes more text than intended to be linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close...

> Why does item have a value of 'item3'? Doesn't the for loop end when i becomes 3?

Yes.

> If it ends shouldn't item still be
>   'item2'?

Nope. This example is a little tricky. During the last iteration of the loop, `i` is 2, but it references the 3rd element of the `list` array, which is 3. In other words, `item == 'item' + list[2] == 'item3'`

> Or is the variable item created again when testList calls the functions?

No, you were almost right the first time.  I think you just missed that `item[2]` has the value of 3.

Comment: Wow that's so simple.  How did I miss that?  The whole start-counting-at-zero thing always messes me up.  Thanks!

Comment: If that was the only obstacle to you understanding javascript closure, give yourself a pat on the back! I think that example was unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 4):

The for loop within buildList completes before you do the following:

```
for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
  fnlist[j]();
}
```

... therefore, by that time (when you call each function), the variable `item` will be whatever was last assigned to it (i.e. "item3"), and `i` will be `3` (as a result of the last `i++` operation), and `list[3]` is `undefined`.

It's all to do with the fact that the loop completes before you call the *closure'd* function. To prevent this, you could create a new closure, like so:

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push(
        (function(item, i){
            // Now we have our own "local" copies of `item` and `i`
            return function() {
                console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])
            };
        })(item, i)
    );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @J-P, Thanks for the great response. I now understand why it was undefined but can I ask why you're example works. Why is there now a new closure created for each of the functions now stored in fnlist?

Comment: That function that's declared and called inside the call to "result.push" creates its own closure.

Comment: @Pointy, Why does it create it's own closure? Because it's an anonymous function?

Comment: @Nick, It creates its own closure simply because it's a function. A function within a function forms a closure... So, on each iteration of the loop we're creating a new closure that will retain the current values of `i` and `item`.

Answer (score 2):

The `list` variable is stored in closure as you say.

Actually you can access the `list` variable, but you are trying to access `list[3]`. After all, the `i` variable is also stored as a closure and it's value is 3 when the `console.log` function is called.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point you are missing is that `list[i]` is underfined because `i` is 3, and `list` is only defined for 0..2.

Answer (score 0):

The loop ends when i becomes 3, but the "item" variable stored in the closure, and displayed by alert, is set to

```
var item = 'item' + list[i];
```

the text 'item' + the value at list[2]. The third list item is 3, so the text is item3