# JQuery callback question

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm trying to assign a different number to different callback functions in jquery.

```
for (i=o;i<types.length;i++) {
     $('#ajax'+types[i]+'Div').html('Loading...').load('searchAjax.php','new=u',function () { $(this).find('select').change( function() { AjaxDiv(i); } ) } );
}
```

Everytime I run this section of code, i is 5 for each call to ajaxDiv because it is calling a global variable. I'm not sure if I can either change the scope of i or if there's a way to print the value in the change function. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance! Happy Thanksgiving!

Andrew

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure and about 80 other questions. (Hint: you need a closure)

Comment: While the others have certainly answered the question, another problem might be that you've set i equal to the letter o...

Answer (score 3):

The callback functions all refer to the same `i` variable, and they are executed when the loop is finished.

You have to capture the `i` variable on the loop:

```
for (i=o;i<types.length;i++) {
  (function (i) {
     $('#ajax'+types[i]+'Div').html('Loading...').load('searchAjax.php','new=u',
     function () {
       $(this).find('select').change( function() { AjaxDiv(i); } )
     } );
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: How many times have you explained this on SO? We need this in the FAQ badly.

Comment: Yes, too many times, a FAQ by language would be nice... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734749/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582634/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933343/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579978/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413916/

Comment: Holy crap. Do not ever delete that comment. There's the reference point right there.