# Delaying css transition with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to delay a css transition of an element based on delay function + additional 0.2s applied on it so it slides 0.2s later than initial delay of main wrapper. I add a class to it which gives it a `transition` to slide from right to left.

If i disable this additional delay (transition-delay), then the element slides fine when initial delay fires up. If i leave it on and add 0.2s additional delay on this inner div then the transition won't work.

Current progress on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qdyeq0x/2/) and jquery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.testPlugin = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            showDiv: false,
            delayIt: null,
            trans: null,
            timing: null,
            speed: null,

        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var self = this;

            // Show main
            if (settings.showDiv == true) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(self).addClass("showIt");
                }, settings.delayIt);
            };

            // Show inner
            $(".inner").addClass(settings.trans + " " + settings.timing + " " + settings.speed).css({
                "transition-delay" : settings.delayIt / 1000 + 0.2 + "s", // if i delete this delay then inner div slides fine
            });

        });
    }
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testDiv").testPlugin({
        showDiv: true,
        delayIt: 500,
        trans: "left",
        timing: "ease",
        speed: "fast",
    });
});
```

Comment: Please include the code in the text of the question, not only the fiddle.

Comment: Sure, edited - thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using setTimeout To Delay A jQuery Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817621/using-settimeout-to-delay-a-jquery-animation)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7qdyeq0x/3/ i didn't got your question properly, though i tried to fix your delay problem

Comment: thanks Sachin for trying - i've edited my question, hope it's clearer now. If you delete the additional transition delay in fiddle you'll see that transform from right to left works. If i leave the delay it doesnt.

Comment: `transform` property given by `left` class is not applied because `inner` div is already having `transform` property specified through id selector. You may want to look into CSS [`specificity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Just wondering, why are you not using CSS transitions? They have delay built into them as well and are GPU accelerated

Comment: @ViperCode He *is* using CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Div with class `inner` has already CSS `transform` property. So, you need to change CSS selector for class 'left' to select through id so that it has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Change

```
.left {
  transform: translateX(20%);
}
```

to

```
#testDiv.showIt .left {
  transform: translateX(20%);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qdyeq0x/5/

Comment: Thanks for explanation and solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I placed your actions with the `".inner"` to the delay timeout.Try with the next code

```
 $.fn.testPlugin = function (options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        showDiv: false,
        delayIt: null,
        trans: null,
        timing: null,
        speed: null,

    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var self = this;

        // Show main
        if (settings.showDiv == true) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(self).addClass("showIt");
                // Show inner
                $(".inner").addClass(settings.trans + " " + settings.timing + " " + settings.speed);

            }, settings.delayIt);
        };


    });
}
```