# Creating a function reference that has value parameters not references

Tags: javascript, function, closures, parameter-passing

I'm not sure exactly how to describe what I want. I want to define a function with the parameters being a local VALUE not a reference.

say I have list of objects I want to create

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.onclick = function(){alert(i);};
  document.appendChild(div);
}
```

Now I believe in this example no matter what div I click on, it would alert "10"; as that is the last value of the variable i;

Is there a way/how do I create a function with the parameters being the value they are at the time I specify the function... if that makes any sense.

Comment: Inside the function, `i` is a captured variable, not a parameter.

Comment: See also: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734749/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643542/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582634/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933343/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579978/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413916/

...and more...  :)

Comment: @CMS: Yes; I've gotten a lot of reputation answering this kind of question.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, I've also answered this question many *many* times, I think at some point we will need a sort of FAQ by *tag* or something like that...

Comment: It's difficult to find existing answers when you're not sure exactly how to phrase the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the function inside another function.

For example:

```
div.onclick = (function(innerI) {
    return function() { alert(innerI); }
})(i);
```

This code creates a function that takes a parameter and returns a function that uses the parameter.  Since the parameter to the outer function is passed by value, it solves your problem.

It is usually clearer to make the outer function a separate, named function, like this:

```
function buildClickHandler(i) {
    return function() { alert(i); };
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.onclick = buildClickHandler(i);
    document.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Now I suppose I have to curry the functions if I want to pass 'this' also?

div.onclick= function(){somefunction(i,this)};

Comment: @Sheldon: Correct.  Alternatively, `someFunc.call(this, i)` will allow you to use `this` inside of `someFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous function:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    (function(i){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.onclick = function(){alert(i);};
        document.appendChild(div);
    })(i)
}
```