# Trouble with Javascript new keyword while using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, new-operator, fabricjs

I am using [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/) to put SVG objects on Canvas element in the HTML. 
But since the FabricJS uses `new` keyword to instantiate classes, I think the properties of that class are getting tied to the `global` namespace.

Below, is my code for reference

My JSON object that I am parsing

```
var defaultSceneObj = [
        {
            "eyes": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_eye.svg",
            "skin": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_skin.svg",
            "mouth": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_mouth_happy.svg",
            "pos": {
                "ground" : "right_back", 
                "sky" : "none", //other values ["none"]
                "relative" : "none" //other values ["none", "top", "bottom"]
            }  
        },
        {
            "eyes": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_eye.svg",
            "skin": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_skin.svg",
            "mouth": "res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_mouth_happy.svg",
            "pos": {
                "ground" : "left_back", 
                "sky" : "none", //other values ["none"]
                "relative" : "none" //other values ["none", "top", "bottom"]
            }  
        }
    ];
```

Which means there are 2 `animals` in my object, where each `animal` is composed of `eye`, `skin` and `mouth` svg files.

I am looping through them in my `javascript` code to render them

```
var renderObjOnCanvas = function(cObj, cDim){
        // console.log("Object, Dimension:", cObj, cDim);
        // var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('elem-frame-svg');
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('elem-frame-svg');

        imgwidth = 200; //default image width
        imgheight = 255; //default image height
        imgScale = 0.6;
        imgOffsetX = Math.floor(imgwidth*imgScale/2);
        imgOffsetY = Math.floor(imgheight*imgScale/2);

        canvaswidth = canvas.width;
        canvasheight = canvas.height;

        // console.log("render canvas dimensions:", canvaswidth, canvasheight); 
        if (cObj.length > 0){

            for (var c =0; c < cObj.length; c++){
                var noun = cObj[c]; //assign the noun object

                if (noun.skin !== 'Undefined'){
                    var animalParts = ['skin', 'eyes', 'mouth'];
                    var pos = cDim.ground[noun.pos.ground];

                    for (var g = 0; g < animalParts.length; g++){

                        var part_top = canvasheight - (pos[1] + imgOffsetY);
                        var part_left = pos[0] - imgOffsetX;
                        console.log("part:", noun[animalParts[g]], "part_position: ", part_top, part_left);

                        var img = new fabric.Image.fromURL(noun[animalParts[g]], function(s){
                            this.top = part_top;
                            this.left = part_left;
                            // this.scale(imgScale);

                            s = this;

                            console.log("part:", part_top, part_left);

                            canvas.add();

                        }); 
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    };
```

The first `console.log` outputs the correct `top` and `left` coordinates, but the second one only outputs the last values assigned and hence all my objects are getting placed on the same position in canvas.

Output for the first `console.log`:

```
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_skin.svg part_position:  282 574 main.js:126
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_eye.svg part_position:  282 574 main.js:126
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_mouth_happy.svg part_position:  282 574 main.js:126
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_skin.svg part_position:  282 135 main.js:126
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_eye.svg part_position:  282 135 main.js:126
part: res/img/animals/cat/cat_part_mouth_happy.svg part_position:  282 135
```

Output for the second `console.log`:

```
(6) part: 282 135
```

Comment: The error could have been because of [this error in Javascript](http://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook?t=24m46s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the forEach manages the scope for the variables for you and whereas for does not. For example,

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   var r = 100;
}
console.log(r); //prints 100 

arr.forEach(function(){
  var w = 100;
});
console.log(w); //prints "w is not defined"
```

so in your case, the part_top, part_left variables exists outside the for loop and only the last assigned value will be taken up by the call back function as variables are passed by reference. Take a look this answer

[scope of variables in JavaScript callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853601/scope-of-variables-in-javascript-callback-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach()` method instead of `for` loop worked for me. Although I am not sure, why

Our closest explanation is that since `forEach()` accepts an anonymous function, it binds the scope of variables into a closure when the `new` operator is invoked.

```
...
if (noun.skin !== 'Undefined'){
                    var animalParts = ['skin', 'eyes', 'mouth'];
                    var pos = cDim.ground[noun.pos.ground];

                    animalParts.forEach(function(item, g){ // <-works
                    // for (var g = 0; g < animalParts.length; g++){

                        var part_top = canvasheight - (pos[1] + imgOffsetY);
                        var part_left = pos[0] - imgOffsetX;
                        console.log("part:", noun[animalParts[g]], "part_position: ", part_top, part_left);

                        var img = new fabric.Image.fromURL(noun[animalParts[g]], function(s){
                            s.top = part_top;
                            s.left = part_left;
                            s.scale(imgScale);
                            // console.log(s, s.top,s.left, part_top, part_left);
                            canvas.add(s);
                        });
                    });
                }
...
```