# Three.js loading textures based on name failing

Tags: javascript, three.js, closures

I have a .obj file that I'm using a loader to load. Inside the object file, I have a bunch of meshes that I want to use individually, kind of like a file that contains everything. However, each "object" has a separate texture. When I try to load it, it tries loading the same texture twice. I have a feeling this is more of a gotcha with JavaScript than three.js. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my current code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++)
    {
        var child = object.children[i]
        child.scale.set(15, 15, 15)
        child.position.y += 0.01
        console.log('Loading texture for: ' + child.name)
        textureLoader.load('assets/' + child.name + '.png', function(image)
        {
            console.log('Looking for: ' + child.name)
            var texture = new THREE.Texture()
            texture.image = image
            texture.needsUpdate = true
            child.material.map = texture
            console.log('Loaded texture for ' + child.name)
        })
    }
    scene.add(object)
```

What ends up happening is only the first object in the list ends up loading. I have verified that the for loop runs  4 times, and each child is different. However, when logging to the console in the callback for textureLoader.load, the name shows up as the first element twice

Comment: Is this an acceptable approach? `for ( var i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++ ) { var child = object.children[ i ]; child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'assets/' + child.name + '.png' ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can write this: console.log('Looking for: ' + child.name)
Because child is defined outside of function(image) and its value may change by the time console.log is called. See this: [scope of variables in JavaScript callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853601/scope-of-variables-in-javascript-callback-functions)

So the above explains why you get repeated printout of same name. But it doesn't explain why you get only two printout. You should get 4 printouts.

If you only get two console.log() outputs then that means that only two .png files were loaded successfully. So make sure all 4 files exists or see if there are actually 2 texture files that are being shared among 4 shapes.

If the problem continues gives us the exact printouts that you get.

**Update 1:** Try this and tell me what output you get?

```
console.log('Loading texture for: ' + object.children[0].name);
textureLoader.load('assets/' + object.children[0].name + '.png', function(image) {
        console.log('Loaded texture for ' + object.children[0].name);
});
console.log('Loading texture for: ' + object.children[1].name);
textureLoader.load('assets/' + object.children[1].name + '.png', function(image) {
        console.log('Loaded texture for ' + object.children[1].name);
});
console.log('Loading texture for: ' + object.children[2].name);
textureLoader.load('assets/' + object.children[2].name + '.png', function(image) {
        console.log('Loaded texture for ' + object.children[2].name);
});
console.log('Loading texture for: ' + object.children[3].name);
textureLoader.load('assets/' + object.children[3].name + '.png', function(image) {
        console.log('Loaded texture for ' + object.children[3].name);
});
```

Comment: If a file fails to load, then  I also get a notification in the console in red text. I'm sure that the image is there, and that three.js is able to load it

Comment: Try the code in Update 1 above and tell me what output you get.